# Proving Cartesian product preserves containment

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C,D$ be finite sets with $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$. Prove that $A\times B\subseteq C \times D$.

Since every element of $A$ is in $C$ and every element of $B$ is in $D$, then every element of $A\times B$ will also be an element of $C\times D$.
However, how would I go about with proving this? Can I assign arbitrary elements to $A,B,C D$?

Comment: What is the definition of $A\times B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence of your second paragraph **is** a proof, albeit an informal one. You could write it up in symbols something like this:

> Let $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$; then $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. $A\subseteq C$, so $a\in C$, and $B\subseteq D$, so $b\in D$, and therefore $\langle a,b\rangle\in C\times D$. Since $\langle a,b\rangle$ was an arbitrary element of $A\times B$, it follows that $A\times B\subseteq C\times D$.